# How do you convert glTF to Cesium 3D Tiles?

Tags: cesiumjs, gltf

There doesn't appear to be any clear way to do this, or existing tools.

Answer (score -3):

I have edited the 3D-Tiles-Tools provided by cesiumjs to convert the gltf to b3dm.
For your reference, here is the link https://github.com/Jennyshining/3d-tiles-tools.git

In the repository, samples-generator/lib/myGenerator.js is the entry.
createGltf is the tool to create gltf, createB3dm and createTilesetJsonSingle are used to create 3d tiles.

Comment: Hi, could not found out how to convert gltf to b3dm in your repository. There are only tools to convert glb(binary gltf) to b3dm